# MediaRecorder Corrupt Video Recording Samsung

Tags: android, video, android-camera, samsung-mobile, android-video-record

I am trying to run Google sample to record 10 second video using `MeadiaRecorder` inside my application. But when playing back recorder video it is getting corrupt.

- Firstly it plays full audio;
- Then plays the first first frame of video;
- Video freezes and nothing happening.

When I browsed the file in explorer it was showing the length to 59 minutes whereas I only stored for 10 seconds and video is not playing as well when trying to play in computer as well.

I am using https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video library as a sample and running same code over the device without any change.

It working fine on all other device except for **Samsung** devices(J7, S5, S6, S8.. etc.)

In above library there is an [open issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/issues/24) as well but still there's no solution provide.

Comment: I've got a report of this issue on a Samsung J6, did you find any solution for it?